# fix background problematic

Tags: html, css

I am creating an application and I want it to have a Fix Background Image in it.
I am using html5, css3 and javascript. 
I made my css to fix my background image like I always do, just like this:

```
 body{ background:#1F1F1F url(../assets/bg.png) fixed;}
```

Ok, Every thing works well in the Browser even if in IE8 and the background image is fixed.
But when it comes to the Default Browser of my Mobile Device the image is not fixed anymore!

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `background-attachment: fixed`, just like `position: fixed` ( http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/ ), seems to be problematic for mobile. See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3301

Comment: Very nice. Thank you very much Ana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried it in an webview or are you just opening it in a browser. I guess if you make an app it will be packed inside a webview. you should try that first and see how that behaves.

Comment: position:fixed is only supported since android browser version 2.2. on what are you testing? and fully supported only since 3.0 see: http://caniuse.com/css-fixed an alternative might be http://cubiq.org/iscroll

Comment: My mobile device is Sumsung Galaxy S2 and its android version is I think 2.3.4

Comment: see my previous comment again. i think its not supported a 100% by the stock browser/webview.

Comment: I don't know what to do.. anyhow thank you for your support man

Comment: no problem there is nothing you can do because it is not fully supported in your android version yet. it only starts at android version 3 and you have 2.3. You can implement it with an alternative like iscroll though for example. or you test your app in an emulator with an android version higher than 3 and make your app only available for those.

Answer (score 1):

How to specify a fixed background-image:

```
body
 { 
 background-color: #1F1F1F;
 background-image:url('../assets/bg.png');
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-attachment:fixed;
 }
```

The background-attachment property sets whether a background image is fixed or scrolls with the rest of the page. The background-attachment property is supported in all major browsers.

Note: The value "inherit" is not supported in IE7 and earlier. IE8 requires a !DOCTYPE. IE9 supports "inherit".